# Objects not being removed without System.gc() call

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, garbage-collection

After having some trouble with object deletion, I ran a simple test:

1. Created a simple class with a **weak reference** listener for Event.ENTER_FRAME.
2. Added a `trace("I Exist!")` call to the listened function.
3. Instantiated a single instance with one reference in the Document Class.

This worked as expected - the SWF file did nothing but print "I Exist!" every frame to the console. (In debug mode, of course.)

What I did next did not work as I expected:
I set the only reference of the object to be set to `null` on a mouse event, but the messages from the event listener of of said object still appeared in the console after the mouse event was fired and the reference set to `null` - meaning the object still existed!

**Calling** `System.gc()` **in the document class IMMEDIATELY stopped the event listener from printing further messages and seemingly deleted the item.**

From what I understand, calling `System.gc()` is discouraged, but as it seems from this simple test the garbage collector is a big FAIL.
Am I doing something wrong here in trying to dispose of the object, or should I simply call `System.gc()` every time I want to get rid of an object..?

**Edit:** Calling `System.gc()` with a non-weak listener also results in the object seemingly being removed from memory (?)

Comment: System.gc() only works in the Flash Player debugger - you won't be able to use it in production.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Garbage collection is almost always deferred in modern VMs (Java, Flash Player, .NET, etc.). You can read http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/garbage_collection.html for more information.

In particular:

> In Flash Player 9, the garbage collector's operations are deferred. This is a very important thing to understand. Your objects will not be removed immediately when all active references are deleted. Rather, they will be removed at some indeterminate time in the future (from a developer standpoint). The garbage collector uses a set of heuristics that look at the RAM allocation and the size of the memory stack, among other things, to determine when to run. As a developer, you must accept the fact that you will have no way of knowing when, or even if, your inactive objects will get deallocated. You must also be aware that inactive objects will continue to execute indefinitely, until the garbage collector deallocates them, so your code will keep running (enterFrame events will continue), sounds will keep playing, loads will keep happening, other events will keep firing, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Actually this is the expected behavior of the Flash garbage collection system. The garbage collection routine runs every time System.gc() is called or a new object is created (new keyword). You should allow GC to naturally clean up objects, and anyways System.gc() only works for the debug player and does nothing for the release version.

If you want the listener from firing, it's ALWAYS best to manual remove the listener yourself with removeEventListener. However, if you don't care about the functionality existing until the next collection phase, you can just rely on the weak listener. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

[Garbage collection is only triggered by allocation in Flash Player](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/as3-fundamentals/garbage-collection.html) meaning setting an object to `null` will not cause the garbage collector to be invoked.

Setting an object to `null` only removes a specific reference to that object. In fact, your listener still has a reference to the object, in your case it's a weak reference so when the GC runs the object is collected but until then it's still hanging out in memory -- dispatching and receiving any events you set it up to handle.

The correct way to handle this is to explicitly remove any event listeners you no longer need, then let the GC do its thing when it's good and ready. Typically I handle this by adding a `destroy()` method to my classes that allow them to clean up their own mess before I do away with them.

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure you removed all references to your object? i.e. did you remove the mouse event listener, if you added the object to the stage, did you removeChild?

Once you're sure all references have been removed, null the object

object = null;

Then importantly call System.gc() TWICE

Garbage collection cal have two phases, Mark and Sweep. Each call of System.gc() only performs one phase.

This is a great article and tool to enable you to track objects in your app to see which objects still have references to them at any point in time.

http://divillysausages.com/blog/tracking_memory_leaks_in_as3

Comment: System.gc() doesn't work for the release version of Flash. It's only meant to do testing. The programmer should never really care when GC runs if you develop things in the right way. I actually like GC to rarely run as I instance all my objects up-front and keep reusing them in the application. Waste not! :)